# HDFS 'No such file or directory' error when trying to copy csv from one directory to another

Tags: hive, hdfs, hortonworks-sandbox

I am using Hortonworks Sandbox (not sure if this matters) and was trying to copy a csv file from '/user/root/' directory into '/user/nyc_taxi/' directory but it gave me a 'No such file or directory' error. I am very sure the csv, called 'yellow_tripdata_2016_01.csv', is in the '/user/root/' directory.

I use Windows 10 and below are the commands I wrote in terminal:

```
>sudo su - hdfs
>hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/root
>hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/nyc_taxi
>hdfs dfs -chown root:hdfs /user/root
>hdfs dfs -chown root:hdfs /user/nyc_taxi
>exit
>hadoop fs -put yellow_tripdata_2016_01.csv /user/nyc_taxi/
```

The first 6 commands had no problem. But when I ran the last one the terminal returned the 'No such file or directory' error. I had also tried specifying the actual path of the csv by running this command:

```
hadoop fs -put /user/root/yellow_tripdata_2016_01.csv /user/nyc_taxi/
```

But the same error message still showed up.

As can be seen from the screenshot below, the csv file is clearly in the '/user/root/' directory.
[image]

Any feedback/recommendation is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**-put** command looks for **yellow_tripdata_2016_01.csv file in local file system not on hdfs.**

But your file is in `HDFS` that's the reason why you are getting that error.

Refer to [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put) link for more details regards to `Hadoop -put/-cp/-mv` commands.

If you want to copy/move the HDFS file into another HDFS directory use below commands

***Copy the file into another hdfs directory:***

```
hadoop fs -cp /user/root/yellow_tripdata_2016_01.csv /user/nyc_taxi/
```

***Move the file into another directory:***

```
hadoop fs -mv /user/root/yellow_tripdata_2016_01.csv /user/nyc_taxi/
```